# Error installing Grub

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, boot-loader, gpt

I'm trying to install grub but I'm getting the error:

```
Warning This GPT partition label contains no BIOS boot partition: 
embedding won't be possible
```

I'm using GPT to partition, and the file system is ext3. When I ran `gdisk -l` it shows the first partitions start sector on the SSD (which is /sda) is 2040.

Am I getting this error because the disk doesn't start on the first 512 bytes?

If not, what else could be causing this error?

I'm trying to get this to work to complete Arch installation.

`parted -l` :

```
Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GTP table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GTP
partition tables. Or prehaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table. Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No: yes
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be. This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller. Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
Fix/Ignore/Cancel? Fix
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the sapce (an extra 6576128 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore/Cancel? Fix
Error: Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
Model: Verbatim (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3932MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

Model: ATA TOSHIBA THNSNH12 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number   Start   End   Size   File system   Flags
 1       0.00B   120GB 120GB  ext3
```

My drive is now `/dev/sdb`. I've just had to wipe it all and start the install again.

Comment: Can you post your "faulty" `parted -l` output, whether my answer helps you or not?

Comment: @Anthon modified question with request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first partition can start at 2040, but it must have the bios_grub flag and that is what your grub install is complaining about.

If you do `parted -l /dev/sda` you should get something like:

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  2150MB  2147MB  ext2
 3      2150MB  36,5GB  34,4GB  btrfs
```